# how to get an object according to parent table field in django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a table named Profile with below code:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth_user', 
           related_name='profile', verbose_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='name')
    family = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='family')
```

and the User table is like below:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_lenght=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_lenght=255)
```

I want to get profiles with username with this function:

```
def get_profile(request, username):
    # some codes
```

how can i get a profile with username?
what should i write in get_profile function?
tanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get()` lookup:

```
def get_profile(request, username=None):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user__username=username)
```

But this can cause an error if there is no such user. So a better approach will be to use [`shortcuts.get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def get_profile(request, username=None):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=username)
```

If you are confused with the *double underscore* syntax (`user__username=username`), check [the docs for field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups).

Comment: I wrote the code you gave to me, but it didn't work. it raises an error with this message: AttributeError at /mojtaba/
type object 'Profile' has no attribute 'model'
not only if i enter a real username, but also when i enter a fake username (that isn't in database), anyway it raises that error.

Comment: that's it: 
def get_profile(request, username=None):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=username)
    print(profile)
    pass

Comment: Try replacing `user_id__username` only with `user__username`.

Comment: didn't work again. may problem related to urlpattern? this is the urlpattern of this function url(r'(?P<username>[\w])/$', views.get_profile, name='profile'), at first i tested it with class-based view and it returned the first error, now i test it with function-based view, all the time it returned 404 error.